# how to set "Underline" when hover on the individual links

Tags: html, css, frontend, css-animations, mousehover

[I want to give Underline Hover effect to this navigation bar please help me with this please how to do that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4Z9S.png)

Comment: Please could you update your question to include the code you already have and let us know what you have tried already? Images of code don't allow people to replicate your issue quickly - meaning you're less likely to get the help you need [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please edit your answer and explain how it works better than what the OP provided.